# Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema is obsolete?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to create a method to validate a Json string with a Json schema using this method: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

It says the object is obsolete and moved to its own package, so I use `NuGet` and install the package (`Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.dll` are references) and have:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    public bool validateSchema(string _Json)
    {
        JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(
                        @"{
                            'properties': {
                                [MySchemaHere]
                        }
                        ");
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(_Json);

        return jobject.IsValid(schema);
    }
```

How do I get rid of the obsolete message? It sounds to me like the code has been moved to the other package/dll, but is called/used in the same way and I'm somehow referencing the obsolete one?  This seems like I'm missing something simple/obvious.

**EDIT:** Here's an image that might help.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PWwpGRx.png]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally just created a new project and copied/pasted their example and I see my painfully obvious mistake that I've been fighting with.

I should be using:

> JSchema

and **not**

> JsonSchema

Comment: To anyone planning to use `JSchema` - note that it is not free for commercial use. Json.NET is released under the MIT license while Json.NET Schema uses the AGPL license (and they specifically say " Companies or incorporated entities with more than 10 employees must purchase a Business plan". 

https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: Why is the obsolete version in the new package? And why doesn't it have a better obsolete message that doesn't make you think you're using the wrong package?

Comment: Ah, it seems maybe they are in separate packages but the namespaces overlap or something of the sort? https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/126

Answer (score 5):

My problem got resolved when I added a new NuGet Package after searching for "JSON.net schema", which resulted in showing another Newtonsoft.Json.Schema Package in option:

Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution

[image]

After doing this, change **JSONSchema** object to **JSchema** object. This will remove the obsolete message and compile the code properly as well.

after:

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";
```

change:

```
            JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
```

to

```
            JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
```

Comment: yes @BrianRogers, spelling mistake. It is supposed to be Compile :)

Comment: after all 3-4 days circus, finally this answer gave the result; thnx Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have this dll? ,your problem seems to be this *JSON Schema validation has been moved to its own package*, check more info here:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema.htm

Hope this help

Comment: I just edited my answer to add an image. As far as I can tell the DLL is added correctly, yes?